# How did the effect in this video?

Tags: editing

Is this all in editing or did they use some sort of infrared camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was apparently made with a [thermal imaging camera](http://www.dezeen.com/2015/04/04/grief-earl-sweatshirt-music-video-hiro-murai-thermal-camera/).